# PHP sessions not working between pages

Tags: php, session, variables, cookies, between

**I've done my research! It still does not work!**

First page:

```
session_start();
$un = $_POST['un'];
$_SESSION['un'] = $un;
```

Second page:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['un'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['un'];
}
```

This is a login system and un stands for username. The variable $_SESSION['un'] is usable in the first page, but as soon as I go to the second page the variable $_SESSION['un'] is not set. I am using a mamp server.

Comment: what do you mean _disappear?_ undefined index? undefined variable? empty string value?

Comment: set `$_SESSION['un'] = 'test';`

Comment: does `$_POST['un']` even have a value to start with?

Comment: The sessions seems to be ended. I cannot use the session variables on the second page.

Comment: Yes, when I post the variable to the first page it works fine, but when I go to the second page I can no longer use that variable that I stored in a session. I am new to php so my wording may be weird.

Comment: unable to reproduce. your code worked fine for me. error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and make sure all files are `.php` and not outputting before header.

Comment: also, are you accessing this as `http://localhost/file.php` or as `file:///file.php`?

Comment: could it be because of my server?

Comment: if it were, error reporting will tell you

Comment: its on a local server. localhost/file.php

Comment: could it have to do with the way I connect with the second page?

Comment: I'M NOT GETTING ANY ERRORS D:. This problem has gone on for like a month now!

Answer (score 0):

Could use !empty for session instead of isset. Here working code Enjoy :P
first page

```
  <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_POST['un']))
        {
        $un = $_POST['un'];
        $_SESSION['un'] = $un;
        header('Location: test2.php');
        }
        ?>

        <form method="post" action="test.php">
            <input type="text" name="un" id="un">
            <input type="submit" name="getun" id="getun">
        </form>
```

Second page

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['un'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['un'];
} 

?>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I import jquery?

Comment: No, the two code samples I provided were on different pages. Two different files

Comment: Then you need 2nd session_start(); try this code in separate files.

Comment: Don't forget to change form action to your first filename. I edited code

Comment: the issue is not the form submission. When I submit the form it goes to a page login.php which displays my username and sets the username to a session variable. I am able to display it fine on the login page, but when I go back to the home the session variables appear to be empty

Comment: Ok don't go there with action from form. do it by adding header(location) at the end. I will edit file. Action must be where data should be send at first. first page.

Comment: @Anton Koening I have first page test.php second test2.php

Comment: The header did not actually redirect. I think it might be to protect popups, but I changed the filenames

Comment: Ok try just to type your second page name in address bar AFTER submission.

Comment: header location was outside isset(post[]) now inside edited.